# Filing taxes in two states with combined income of over $106,800

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, form-w-2

A friend of mine resides in CA full time but has two jobs and received a W-2 from California and one from Utah (he never lived in or had residency in Utah). His W-2 from each state was around $70,000.

He had two questions:

1) Does he have to file in both states? How does he make sure he doesn't get taxed by CA on the income he already paid to Utah?

2) His combined income is over $106,800 (the limit for Social Security/Medicare), however each state withheld the full amount so he has paid SS/Medicare on $140,000 of income. Would he just get a larger federal refund of the amount he shouldn't have paid?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The social security taxes are withheld not by the state but by the company. Each company you work for is required to withhold up the maximum amount. They have no knowledge about any other jobs you have. The excess funds will be returned as part of the tax return (the tax software packages pick this up very easily). There in no maximum amount for Medicare, the tax is withheld by each company for every dollar you earn.

Comment: Was the work site for one of the jobs in Utah?

Comment: I believe he telecommuted from California.

Comment: It will depend on how he filled out his Federal and State W-4 tax forms, and what is the reciprocity between the two states. His pay stubs while working for the Utah company should have been telling him the tax money was going to Utah.

Comment: "How does he make sure he doesn't get taxed by CA on the income he already paid to Utah?" He will be taxed by California on his Utah income because California taxes its residents on all their worldwide income.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,it would be necessary to file tax returns in both states.

First, complete the Federal tax return. If your friend itemizes
deductions, the *income* taxes *withheld* (and thus paid) to 
both States during 2012
are deductible on Schedule A of your Federal Form 1040 for 2012
(as well as taxes paid in 2012 for previous years, e.g. accompanying
the 2011 tax return filed during 2012).
On page 2 of Form 1040,
your friend will get the *excess* contributions for Social Security
tax as a *credit* (meaning it will reduce the Federal income tax owed
or increase the Federal tax return). The *States* of California and
Utah have nothing to do with this matter, even if the excess 
withholding was done by the States as your friend's *employers*.

Next, your friend should complete a *nonresident* income tax
return for Utah. Many states compute state income tax for
nonresidents as follows.
Compute the state income tax $Z on the total income $X reported on 
the Federal 1040 as per state rules for nonresidents.  If $Y
is the income 
attributable to the State, then the tax owed to the State is
($Z)*(Y/X). But, regardless of how Utah computes the
state income tax, this tax return needs to be completed
before the California tax return.

Finally, your friend needs to complete the California state
income tax return for *residents*. There will typically be a credit for
income taxes paid to Utah, though this credit might not be
the *entire* amount paid to Utah. That is, your friend will
be "taxed twice" on at least some part of the income.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Does he have to file in both states? How does he make sure he
>   doesn't get taxed by CA on the income he already paid to Utah?

He has to file in both states. He's going to pay CA taxes on all the salaries (both the CA and Utah), and Utah taxes on the Utah salary. CA allows credit for other state taxes.

> 2) His combined income is over $106,800 (the limit for Social
>   Security/Medicare), however each state withheld the full amount so he
>   has paid SS/Medicare on $140,000 of income. Would he just get a larger
>   federal refund of the amount he shouldn't have paid?

Yes, there's a line on 1040 for that in the "Payments" section (line 69). See the 1040 instructions and [publication 505](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p505/ch03.html#en_US_2012_publink1000248735) on the specifics.